# onClick open module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
//Home.js

import React from "react";


function Header() {
  return (
      <div className="header__search">
        <ImageSearchIcon onClick = { Upload_img }/>
      </div>  
  );
}

export default Header;
```

```
//Upload_img.js

import React, {useState} from "react";
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';


const Upload_img = (props) => {

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleOpen = () => { 
        setOpen(true);
      };
    
      const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
      };

    return (
        <div>
        <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        ><h1>hello</h1></Modal>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Upload_img
```

I would like to use modal as module
But I am getting this kind of error

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: What is behind ImageSearchIcon? Because it seems like weird syntax for onClick to receive object with actual functional component, instead of handler function.

Comment: ImageSearchIcon is just an icon from material-ui, how can I use handler function in this case?

Comment: What occurs now, you pass functional component (that acts as a function right now) that returns some DOM element. `const Upload_img = (props) => { return (<div />)}`, it means that `<ImageSearchIcon onClick = { Upload_img }/>` will receive that element. `onClick = {<div />}` but it does not render it. Just expects a handler (I assume). If you would please provide specific component from `material-ui` that you use, I could look what it expects, because I am making assumptions right now. As I can't find `ImageSearchIcon` inside https://material-ui.com/ you probably rename it on import.

Comment: Thank you so much for specific comment! 'import ImageSearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ImageSearch';'  <--I imported this one. I now understand that I was giving <div>tags in onclick event. (Plus I misunderstood about module,  I was meaning component, I wanted to say 'onClick open from another component' in the title)

Comment: I would like to make modal pop up when I click ImageSearchIcon. How can I make this?

Comment: Actually @Ammar provided little example how to achieve this, have you tried it?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that comment. That comment helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to solve this issue. I believe the easiest way is to move your modal state in the parent (Header) component.

```
//Home.js

import React from "react";


function Header() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => { 
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
      <div className="header__search">
        <ImageSearchIcon onClick={handleOpen}/>
        <Upload_img open={open} handleOpen={handleOpen} handleClose={handleClose}  />
      </div>  
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Now your Upload_img component will be a stateless component and it will look like this:

```
//Upload_img.js

import React from "react";
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';


const Upload_img = ({open, handleClose, handleOpen}) => {
    return (
        <div>
        <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        ><h1>hello</h1></Modal>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Upload_img
```

Comment: Look at this example as it shows how function handler should be written and passed down. (pointing from my comment)